# Alfresco, Tomcat6 and javascript handling of ISO date strings

Tags: javascript, date, alfresco, activiti

Part of the webscripts I've written for my Alfresco/Activiti workflow support a request that takes a date/time in ISO format.

```
2012-10-23T16:52:08
```

I was thinking that Javascript Date object should be able to handle this, especially in the version of Tomcat that Alfresco installer uses. ( Tomcat6 running on a Window 2003 Server).

Simple enough...

```
var dDate = new Date( "2012-10-23T16:52:08" );
```

This results in an invalid date. I realize that ISO date format handling is a recent (2009-2010?) addition to the ECMA script specification.

Can the Tomcat6/Alfresco javascript parsing engine handle ISO date strings? If not, is there something I can update so that it can?

According to this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse    I need to use Javascript version 1.8.5
How can I update the javascript parsing logic of Alfresco/Tomcat to that version, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Alfresco specific JavaScript functions are described in the [Alfresco JavaScript API wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API)

The bit you want is one of the [utility functions](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Utility_Functions) on the `utils` object:

> Date fromISO8601(string)
>
> ```
>     Parse a Date from ISO8601 formatted string
> ```

So you'll want to do something like:

```
 var dDate = utils.fromISO8601( "2012-10-23T16:52:08" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the timezone to the date, e.g. 2012-10-23T16:52:08+00:00 or 2012-10-23T16:52:08Z. The documentation on MDN states that it is a **subset** of ISO 8601 that can be used from JavaScript 1.8.5, so presumably if you specify the full format then that will work in older versions.

As a sidenote, the engine used to interpret server-side JS in Alfresco is Mozilla's Rhino.

Comment: Thanks for the JS engine tip. I've tried all the various ISO date formats with no luck, though.